# WordPress enqueue JS, jQuery and other libraries

Tags: wordpress-theming

Here’s what I do in an ordinary html file.

```
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
```

Now, I’d like to see this reflected in WordPress. So in my functions.php I do this:

```
function theme_files(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery',get_theme_file_uri('js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js'),NULL,'1.0',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('popper',get_theme_file_uri('js/popper.min.js'),NULL,'1.0',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap',get_theme_file_uri('js/bootstrap.min.js'),NULL,'1.0',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('ui',get_theme_file_uri('js/jquery-ui.min.js'),NULL,'1.0',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('ownJS',get_theme_file_uri('js/scripts.js'), array('jquery'), '1.0',true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_files');
```

Unfortunately it doesn’t work. I already found out that its not the dependency in my own js (scripts.js). It doen’t matter whether I do NULL or array(‚jquery‘). Also, I tried to only enqueue my own js without the others. Doen’t seem to change a thing.

Suprisingly, when I do `alert(’test’);` in my scripts.js it does pop up. But when I do

```
$(„#idOne“).click(function(){
    alert(‚hello‘);
});
```

Nothing happens when I click on the element with the id=„idOne“

Even when I do pure js

```
function sayHi(){
    alert(‚Hi‘);
}

var one = document.getElementByID(‚idOne‘);
one.addEventListener(‚click‘,sayHi, false);
```

it doesn’t do a thing ether. What do I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you replace `NULL` with either `false`or `array()`?

Comment: have you seen the browser console to check if there are any errors with your scripts?

Comment: false or array() instead of NULL didn't help. Thanks, though! I indeed checked the console. Its seems that I simpy need to replace $("#idOne")... by jQuery("#idOne")... I can't say why pure js didn't work at first. It does now but I really can't see what I've changed. - Thanks again!!